# Windows Firewall allows the connection to more than one user who shares the same external IP address

Tags: windows, firewalls, nat

I wrote a stand-alone anticheat. When the client anticheat connects to its server, the server creates a firewall rule allowing the game client to gain access to the server.

The problem is the firewall creates rules by IP address. If NAT is used, then one of the NATed IPs accesses the anticheat server, this server creates a firewall rule for all IPs behind the NAT.

How can I solve this "NAT" issue? Is it possible to solve this using Windows firewall API?

I don't want to block NAT'ed connections, I want to allow it if there is a way to authenticate users' devices with Windows firewall on the anticheat server first.

The anticheat server and game server are on the same PC.
Windows firewall blocks all inbound connections for the game. The only way you can connect to the game server is to authenticate first with the anticheat server. But, firewall add rules by IP address. If I have two users with the same external IP, one of them accesses with anticheat client and the other has no need to do it because the server already made a rule for the IP.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You decide for whatever reason to implement your anticheat service in a specific (but unknown to us) way and now you run into problems with this kind of approach you did not anticipate in the design. Instead of changing the design you want to work around the particular problem. Maybe this is possible but I think more information are needed about the design in general, the objectives you try to achieve with it, why it was implemented to rely on IP addresses in the first place etc.

Comment: It is not xy problem. Im giving the problem and enough information. The anticheat system was mainly made for LAN's but network grown up and now some IP address are behind NAT. Thats why i'm facing this problem now. The idea was use Windows firewall API in order to restrict game client connections. Of course, the anticheat server is in the same pc along with game server. The only way you can connect to game is connect with anticheat server first. If you don't do this, firewall does not create a rule for you

Comment: The way I understand your problem then is that it is not about detecting cheating but to make sure that a firewall rule allows access by an IP address if __at least__ one client is behind this IP? I.e. it is more about preventing denial of service attacks against your service than to prevent actual cheating. Because at the IP level you would not be able to detect a specific client/user anyway, this would require some authentication at the application level. Am I right?

Comment: It is not an anticheat question or ddos attack. Is a network question. I put anticheat word because is a problem with my anticheat server but not a problem detecting cheats. The main problem is that Windows firewall create rules by IP. Then if users behind NAT share the same external IP just one user is need it for auth with anticheat server. Other users sharing the same IP have no need to auth with anticheat server because the Nat

Comment: Correct. This means that the IP address alone is not sufficient as a feature to authenticate a specific client. No firewall rules magic can work around this inherent limitation. Authentication of a client need to be done at a different level than the IP address. And that's why I still think it is an XY problem - where X is the problem that you somehow want to authenticate a client and Y is the way you choose to implement it, i.e. authentication by IP. Only approach Y cannot work by the inherent limitations of this approach if NAT is involved.

Comment: Fine, you win. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I'm dealing with this a long time ago. And still have not enough information.

Comment: *"Any ideas"* - hard to tell without knowing more about the application. But if you want to keep the design of having a separate anti-cheat and application service than a common design would be to let the anti-cheat service issue some signed token after successful check and let the client send this token when connecting to the application service. The service then can verify the signature on the token and thus can make sure that this specific client passed the test. This is similar to approaches done within windows networks, OAuth2, SAML etc.

Comment: What you are describing is the idea of "authenticated sessions" that has been used by the web for a very long time. The game server should be managing sessions.

Comment: the idea is that the anti-cheat server has as few dependencies as possible on the game server. In my case I speak of none. imagine I have three PCs. one is the server (game and anti-cheat) and the other two clients that are behind a NAT. Remember that I use the windows firewall to deny entry to the game service as long as you have not authenticated with the anti-cheat server. And if you are behind a NAT network, it is enough for one IP to authenticate in the anti-cheat server, the others can bypass the firewall

Comment: When you authenticate on the anti-cheat server, it creates a rule for you in the firewall that allows you to enter the game server with its client

Comment: Which is why you have a X-Y-problem. You want to authenticate clients. You think a firewall (which can - in this case - only distinguish users by IP) is the solution. Because of shared IP's (NAT) it doesn't work the way you want. Your problem is really that the best solution is ***not*** simple firewalling. Which application is additionally relevant, as it may be possible to add autentication to this protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what you state in the comments, this *is* an xy-problem. An xy-problem is "how can I use x to do y" while not even considering whether x is an appropriate method to do y.

If you want to distinguish between clients behind a NAT (your y), an IP-based firewall (your x) is *not* the appropriate solution. Possible solutions are

- use VPNs if you must (seems disproportionately heavy in this context)
- authenticate the sessions and allow only authenticated sessions, for example via a proxy
- separate the anticheat and game server on different (possibly virtual) machines
- et cetera.

In short, the answer to your question is, that Windows "firewall" is an IP based filter and you cannot reliably distinguish between host behind a NAT router.

Comment: Great, I've been reading about proxies but I've only seen them work on web and not desktop applications. Let's say that the proxy's ip will always be allowed in the firewall and the authentication will be done by the proxy. That is valid for me. Now where can I find useful information to achieve this. Take into account that the language I master is C #. I'm learning C ++ to create kernel-mode drivers but that's another matter.

Comment: Look at SOCKS proxies. Disclaimer: I don't know anything about your original problem, so I cited this as an option only. It may not be applicable either.

Comment: Ok, after a lot of researching I finally make a proxy and a login session at the protocol level